# Spring boot and Keycloak

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

I'm using this example: **https://github.com/foo4u/keycloak-spring-demo**

I have keycloak.json file in my WEB-INF folder, but when I run my application, I get this exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Must set 'realm' in config
```

Full stack of this exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Must set 'realm' in config
    at org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.internalBuild(KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.java:53) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-2.4.0.Final.jar:2.4.0.Final]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.build(KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.java:152) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-2.4.0.Final.jar:2.4.0.Final]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver.resolve(KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver.java:37) ~[keycloak-spring-boot-adapter-2.4.0.Final.jar:2.4.0.Final]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.AdapterDeploymentContext.resolveDeployment(AdapterDeploymentContext.java:88) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-2.4.0.Final.jar:2.4.0.Final]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.PreAuthActionsHandler.preflightCors(PreAuthActionsHandler.java:107) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-2.4.0.Final.jar:2.4.0.Final]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.PreAuthActionsHandler.handleRequest(PreAuthActionsHandler.java:79) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-2.4.0.Final.jar:2.4.0.Final]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.invoke(AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:183) ~[keycloak-tomcat-core-adapter-2.4.0.Final.jar:2.4.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_101]
```

This code is just an example of integration between Spring boot and Keycloak.

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your answer and time.

Comment: Hi , can you post the keycloak.json file? and have you followed all the steps for the realm creation on the keycloak server?

Comment: Hi my keycloak.json file looks like:
{
  "realm": "master",
  "auth-server-url": "someURL",
  "resource": "resourceName",
  "credentials": {
    "secret": "someSecret"
  },
  "principal-attribute": "preferred_username"
}

Comment: So you're trying to use the master realm?

Comment: Yes, I am trying use master realm.

Comment: ok never done something like that. I have to verify...

Comment: OK thanks very much ...

Comment: How looks like? :)

Comment: You should not try to use master realm and use spring-realm instead. The tutorial you posted already says that you need to import the spring-realm at first that is in the root of the project.

Answer (score 1):

Even though that's a good and valid example, that dates from 2015. I believe it uses Keycloak 1.2.0 which is completely outdated. There are a set of examples with Spring [here](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/tree/master). Most of them up to date with the latest changes.

I suggest taking a look at these examples and read the [docs](http://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_spring_boot_adapter) as well.

Comment: These are still using Sprin Boot 1.5.3, which is very outdated. If there are any examples for KeyCloak with Spring Boot 2, please share.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using keycloak adapter with spring boot 2 or spring boot 1.5, you have to mentioned below properties in application.properties or application.yaml file

```
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8180/auth
keycloak.realm=abc
keycloak.resource=movie-app
keycloak.public-client=false
keycloak.principal-attribute=preferred_username
```

If it still gives the error, please post the error, i will share the code :)