# authorize users in my project and get access_token from keycloak

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, keycloak

I have a project in springboot + springSecurity oauth2
this project is work correctly.
I want to add keycloak to this project.
I want to authorize users in my project and get `access_token` from keycloak.
Is this possible?

Comment: Why not do some research and give it a try? I mean, "keycloak springboot" as web search terms gets immediate hits, including what looks like a tutorial. SO is not great for tutorial style questions. Or even https://stackoverflow.com/q/41056124/1531971

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring boot and Keycloak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41056124/spring-boot-and-keycloak)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [article](https://medium.com/@bcarunmail/securing-rest-api-using-keycloak-and-spring-oauth2-6ddf3a1efcc2), how to use oauth2 with spring security and keycloak